Unknown identifier 'user_id' in aggregate function
I have a sql script
SELECT 
    toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsReg), 'Etc/GMT-3')) AS event_date, 
    idProject, 
    uniqExact(logins.idUser) / coalesce(uniqExact(regs.idUser),0) AS users 
FROM logins AS logins
LEFT JOIN regs AS regs 
    ON regs.idProject = logins.idProject 
    AND regs.dtEvent = toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsReg), 'Etc/GMT-3'))
WHERE 
    dateDiff('day', toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsReg), 'Etc/GMT-3')), toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsEvent), 'Etc/GMT-3'))) = {day_num}
GROUP BY 
    event_date, 
    regs.dtEvent
    idProject

I get the error

Unknown identifier 'user_id' in aggregate function

I've tried running this
SELECT 
    toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsReg), 'Etc/GMT-3')) AS event_date, 
    idProject, 
    coalesce(uniqExact(regs.idUser),0) AS users 
FROM logins AS logins
LEFT JOIN regs AS regs 
    ON regs.idProject = logins.idProject 
    AND regs.dtEvent = toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsReg), 'Etc/GMT-3'))
WHERE 
    dateDiff('day', toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsReg), 'Etc/GMT-3')), toDate(toTimeZone(toDateTime(logins.tsEvent), 'Etc/GMT-3'))) = {day_num}
GROUP BY 
    regs.event_date, 
    regs.dtEvent
    regs.idProject

still get the same mistake
and tried to use subqueries
but I get this mistake

"message": "Code: 288.
DB::Exception: Double-distributed IN/JOIN
subqueries is denied (distributed_product_mode = 'deny')

.

I assume you're executing this over a distributed table? You can set distributed_product_mode=allow/local/global depending on your data distribution.
Ensuring you get the correct result here is going to depend on  how the data is located and whether you really need a GLOBAL join or local joins can be performed. Recommend https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/operators/in#distributed-subqueries
